# How to compare values in arrays using usort function?

Tags: php, arrays

create three arrays and compare the value in the array.

```
$array1 = array ("red", "yellow", "brown", "green");
$array2 = array ("green", "yellow", "black", "red");
$array3 = array ("red", "yellow", "brown", "black");
```

Comment: 1) You misspelled `usort` in code. 2) Is this some sort of homework? This is not the ideal function for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect) it's much more appropriate for this question

Comment: Also, shouldn't "red" be in the result as well? It appears in all three arrays.

Comment: Result is only yellow

Comment: I believe you need to add the whole assignment, because it's currently not clear what and how exactly you need to achieve here.

Comment: Create 3 array Write a code to compare the values in array 1,2,and 3, then output the values which are in array 1, 2, and 3. Your output should be similar or the same Array ( [2]=>yellow ) .

Comment: It doesn't mention `usort` anywhere, so why do you keep insisting on using it? Also, it clearly states you need values that are present in all three. Using that logic, in your example, "red" should be included in the result too. It says output should be similar, not identical.

Comment: yeah, that's true but I need to do sort an array by values using user-defined comparison function this is usort function. Ans may be [1] => yellow not red that's question

Comment: That's why I asked for the *whole* assignment. The rules aren't clear from what you posted so far. Please include all of the instructions you must adhere to (by editing the question, so they don't remain obscured in the comments).

Comment: This is only a question and there are no any rules or guides. I edited a post that's only instructions are given. Don't bother too much if you give me any idea then its fine.

Comment: usort() is used for sorting an array in a customized way, not comparing values between arrays.

Comment: @El_Vanja - OP needs the values to  be identical at the same keys. (so if yellow is identical at key 1 on every three arrays, while red is included in all arrays but are not at the same position(key) (red is 0,3 and 0) while yellow is at key :1,1,1

Comment: @Nick - I thought intersect would be good as well but I don't think works if you want only want to include valeus within the same keys of arrays?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld given the comments, array_intersect_assoc is the way to go. See my answer.

Comment: @Nick - aha . it works with the _assoc -part. Thx :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, a simple foreach of the first array, then match that all arrays have the value, if so add it to an array.

```
<?php
$array1 = array ("red", "yellow", "brown", "green");
$array2 = array ("green", "yellow", "black", "red");
$array3 = array ("red", "yellow", "brown", "black");

$matched = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($array2[$key] === $value && $array3[$key] === $value) {
        $matched[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($matched);
```

https://3v4l.org/F052a

```
Array
(
    [1] => yellow
)
```

you won't get index `2` as yellow is at `1`

You could also use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$array1 = array_filter($array1, function ($value, $key) use ($array2, $array3) { 
   return $array2[$key] === $value && $array3[$key] === $value;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

https://3v4l.org/H7d9D

Comment: How can I get output using usort function ? without foreach

Comment: usort wont reduce your array so its not possible with that alone

Comment: Can you please tell any other method compare function and usort ?

Comment: what your after is not built in (or I forgot - *dont use php much anymore*). you could replace the foreach with array_walk

Comment: Did  @LawrenceCherone answer help here James?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_intersect_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) for this problem, as it will only return equal values in each array that *also have the same keys*:

```
$array1 = array ("red", "yellow", "brown", "green");
$array2 = array ("green", "yellow", "black", "red");
$array3 = array ("red", "yellow", "brown", "black");

print_r(array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2, $array3));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => yellow
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EPTSE)